# Element created with XSLT templating not visible by Selenium

Tags: selenium, xslt, webdriver-io

The problem is that when I try to set a value to an input, selenium return the following error:
*RuntimeError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with*

Howhever, the input is completly visible. In this test I'm using Firefox because is the browser where the application is correctly loaded.

I can't change the application code and the app has a lot of legacy code but I have recreated the most simple example where you can see the issue.

Do you know any workaround without modifying the application code?

I'm using webdriverio:

```
this.browser
    .url('http://localhost/main.xml')
    .setValue('[name=inputId]', 'aaaaaaaa')
    .close()
    .then(callback)
```

main.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="main.xsl" ?>
<CONTEXTO></CONTEXTO>
```

main.xsl content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>

    <xsl:include href="helper.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="CONTEXTO">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Test main</title>
                <style>
                    * { margin:0; }
                    form { position: absolute; }
                    input { border: 1px black solid; }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form name="" action="" method="POST">
                    <label for="inputId">inputId
                        <input type="text" name="inputId" id="inputId" value="" />
                    </label>
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

helper.xsl content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <script></script>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CONTEXTO"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have hit a limitation with Selenium with XML content, as it is treated differently by browsers than HTML content. You can try to fix this by using SendKeys instead. But if it cannot find the element, you will have to get to the element by key navigation, which can be tricky.

Alternatively, try finding the element with [`find_element_by_name` or `find_element_by_id` or use XPath](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html) or [this webdriver.io alternative](http://webdriver.io/api/action/selectorExecute.html). If none work, you can find out by traversing the tree from root node to the next. If none work, then my guess is, that Selenium sees the XML DOM (try to find the root element), not the XSLT-generated DOM.

Comment: Thanks @Abel. I can find the element using Selenium but doesn't recognize as visible. Using selectorExecute method of webdriver.io it return this error: RuntimeError: waiting for doc.body failed. I have found an [issue about this in Selenium Developers group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/selenium-developer-activity/OCCabUAE4Vw/VN7NyREIHk8J) and it seems to be a bug in firefox to execute js in browser when the xml document is bad formed.

Comment: @atena, if the XML document is badly formed, the XSLT will not even run properly. If you load the document without Selenium, does it render properly? If you inspect source you'll see the rendered XML, is it well-formed and valid (perhaps the processor starts, and breaks of when it finds illegal content, which is an allowed and standards-compliant method with XSLT)

Comment: Yes, @Abel, the application is part of an old intranet and it just work in some firefox and ie versions. I think that the problem are the script tags that include before the html tag but this is something that i can't change.

Comment: @atena, Ouch, script tags before html tag? That's very illegal. It turns the HTML, which is required to have one root element, into a non-document with two root documents. In XSLT this is allowed to create that, but not to process it. I can understand that it gives trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Trying waiting for the input value to exist first:

```
.waitForExist('[name=inputId]', 1000)
.setValue('[name=inputId]', 'aaaaaaaa')
```

Comment: Thanks jrader. The input exist but continue invisible for selenium.

Comment: you get the error even after using waitForExist? What error do you get back?

Comment: @atena, my guess is, you hit a bug with Selenium, or a bug with webdriver-io. You should report it. But I doubt they do much about it, this type of rendering (XML file with xsl-stylesheet PI) is very rarely used in real production environments (you deleted your comment under my answer, so I am reposting here)

Comment: @jrader, yes, the error: RuntimeError: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Comment: @Abel, sorry, i had a mistake with the comment :) About the bug, yes I reported this bug few days ago at the Selenium community (the same error is returned trying to do it from Ruby too) but nobody approved it yet. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the XSL is generating a malformed HTML. The helper is going to match `/` and generate a script tag and apply the `CONTEXTO` template, leading to a document such as:

```
<script></script>
<html>....</html>
```

That doesn't have too much sense as HTML.

For some reason firefox's TransformiIX engine in this situation is ignoring the output method `HTML` and is falling back to `text` output, which leads to the inclusion of a wrapper tag called `transformiix:result`. (see this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT/Using_the_Mozilla_JavaScript_interface_to_XSL_Transformations) for reference).

You can check this, like I did, by issuing a getPageSource() to the webdriver and printing it to the log. You'll see the resulting output of the transformation is:

```
<transformiix:result>
    <script></script>
    <html>....</html>
</transformiix:result>
```

This is making webdriver be totally unable to interact with the page.

The recommended way to solve it is to fix the XSLT. If that's not an option (very big impact), the you can execute the following script using webdriver's executeScript, right after the page load (or before the first interaction attempt with the page).

```
document.getRootNode().replaceChild(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0], document.getElementsByTagName('transformiix:result')[0])
```

This will replace the documents root node `transformiix:result` when present with the `html` tag.

Note that if in your current development, you have more stuff included by your helper.xsl, you might need to also take those tags and move then inside the header tag as part of the script above.

---

Edit: You can also reproduce the XSL issue by executing the following code in a firefox debug window:

```
//Execute in a firefox inspect console
var p = new XSLTProcessor();

var toTransform = document.implementation.createDocument(null, "CONTEXTO");

var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlString = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <script></script>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CONTEXTO"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="CONTEXTO">
        <html>
            <body>
                Hello
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
`;

p.importStylesheet(parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml"));

var doc = p.transformToDocument(toTransform);
console.log(doc.getRootNode().children[0].outerHTML);
```